# Can I emulate ROS node level "design by contract" with self_test?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to emulate "design by contract" on the ROS node level by using [diagnostics/self_test](https://github.com/ros/diagnostics/tree/master/self_test). To check a ROS nodes preconditions probably [`pretest()` (self_test example)](https://github.com/ros/diagnostics/blob/master/self_test/src/selftest_example.cpp#L85) could be used. The ROS nodes postconditions could be checked with [`posttest()` (self_test example)](https://github.com/ros/diagnostics/blob/master/self_test/src/selftest_example.cpp#L161). Could I trigger self_test test function execution when topics are published somehow?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272074/can-i-emulate-ros-node-level-%22design-by-contract%22-with-self_test?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2017-10-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-02**:
I guess this will depend on what it is you want to test / what is in your contract.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2017-10-04**:
The list of possible preconditions, postconditions and invariants which could be checked is long. The question is how checks could be executed in general. pretest() should work before ROS node startup (e.g. check if dependent on nodes are already running)...

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2017-10-04**:
... invariant checking could be done whenever a node received a topic message or a service request which could potentially change the node into an invalid state. The question is if it would be possible with self_test to use kind of callback function mechanism which would allow to execute checks then

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-04**:
I don't think that `self_test` was intended to be used that way (it's more a "runtime testing" tool for diagnostic purposes), but perhaps it could be repurposed.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2017-10-04**:
I know. I am just thinking about if self_test could be used to support design by contract, built-in-selftesting, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

self_test is not suitable to emulate "Design By Contract".

However self_test is not required to emulate DbC with self_test at all but would be overhead instead. It is sufficient to implement "assert" functions for parameter values, topics message values, service request/response message values and action goal/result/feedback topic message values and call them in corresponding "sections" of nodes. For "asserting" different alternatives come to mind: diagnostics `status.summaryf(diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticStatus::ERROR, "DbC violation"` or logging `rospy.logerr("DbC violation")`.

---

Originally posted by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) with karma: 468 on 2017-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0